# how to transfer the namespace using xslt

Tags: xslt

Is it possible to change the namespaces from xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Message xmlns:ns1="http://www.rof.com/schemas/">
<Head Release="1.2.0" TransDate="2018-08-07T23:39:00" SplitLevel=""/>
<Data>
  <Business BusinessId="ROF">
  </Business>
</Data>
</ns1:Message>
```

to below using XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rof:Message xmlns:rof="http://www.rof.com/schemas/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.rof.com/schemas/
http://www.rof.com/schemas/4.9.5/2001/message.xsd">
<Head Release="1.2.0" TransDate="2018-08-07T23:39:00" SplitLevel=""/>
<Data>
  <Business BusinessId="ROF">
  </Business>
</Data>
</rof:Message>
```

Comment: You are not actually changing the namespace here, but the namespace prefix. Strictly speaking the namespace prefix really shouldn't matter, unless you are dealing with a system that doesn't process them as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an identity transformation.

XSLT 2.0 solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:rof="http://www.rof.com/schemas/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:element name="rof:{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: Added fix to just change the namespace of the root node, removed copying unneccessary namespace nodes.

Comment: That way the children the root element will continue to have the namespace declaration `xmlns:ns1="http://www.rof.com/schemas/"` in scope and it will be output, see http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qM2e2g. So the identity transformation without `copy-namespaces="no"` does not suffice to create the wanted output.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you are right. If you don't want unnecessary namespace nodes, you have to set copy-namespaces="no". I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Right, but `copy-namespaces` is not available in XSLT 1.0 so you have to remove that remark of "make it compatible with XSLT 1.0" after that XSLT 2 code sample.

Comment: Yes ... that's the downside ;) Actually, I overlooked that the poster did only want to change the prefix, not the actual namespace, so I guess one could probably have a simpler solution here. Anyway, I remove XSLT 1.0 from my answer.